# How to read the data from javascript in jtemplate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, jtemplates

i have got the json data in my js file and now i need to pass the same to jtemplate and display. Here is the code i tried, but no data is getting displayed

```
   $.ajax({
            url: '/CMananager/getDetails',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: { 'ID': ID },
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {

                var placeHolder = $("#templatePlaceHolder");

                placeHolder.setTemplateURL("/Templates/Preview/Details.htm");


                placeHolder.processTemplate(result.Name);
            }
```

In jtemplate i'm trying to read the data like this, nothing is getting displayed

```
<input type="text" id="Details" name="DetailsName" style="float:left; font-size:14px; line-height:42px; padding: 0; text-align: left;width: 80%;" value="{$T.Name}" maxlength="50"/>

<span id="DetailsNamespan" style="float:left; font-size:14px; line-height:42px; padding: 0; text-align: left;width: 80%;">{$T.Name}</span>
```

Comment: Try with `placeHolder.processTemplate({Name: result.Name});`

Comment: Super it worked, but may i know the reason please. why do i have to assign to another variable and access there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$T` references the data object what you pass in to the template.

So if you want to reference your data with `{$T.Name}` then you need to pass in an object which has a `Name` property:

```
placeHolder.processTemplate({Name: result.Name});
```

Or if you only want to pass in a simple type (string, number, etc) you can do it but in this case you need to use `{$T}` to access it in the template:

```
placeHolder.processTemplate(result.Name);
```

And in your template:

```
<input type="text" id="Details" name="DetailsName" value="{$T}" />

<span id="DetailsNamespan">{$T}</span>
```